# KeyError when annotating on plot in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, annotations

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as date
from pandas_datareader import data as web
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors


start = date.datetime(2018,1,1)
end = date.datetime.today()

xl_file = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\user\randomdates.xlsx')
xl_file.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
xl_file.index = pd.to_datetime(xl_file.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')

stock = 'BTC-USD'
data = web.DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end)
fig , ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 4))

data.plot(y='Close', ax = ax)
newdates = xl_file.loc[start:end]
for anotate in (xl_file.index):
    ax.annotate(anotate, xy=(anotate, data['Close'].loc[anotate]),  xycoords='data',
                xytext=(-30, 40), textcoords='offset points',
                size=13, ha='center', va="baseline",
                bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", alpha=0.1),
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="wedge,tail_width=0.5", alpha=0.1));
```

The excel file i mentioned has the following entry in it:

[image]

The dates are random and i got these dates with the following excel formula:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2018, 1, 1),DATE(2019, 10, 20))
```

For some reason the plot is generated for the `pandas_datareader` but it is not `annotating` on the plot. I keep getting the following error and am not sure what to make of it:

```
KeyError: 1514764800000000000
```

Please advise what can i do to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Pandas inbuilt way of handling dates called `pandas.to_datetime()` which will convert your column to the date format.

Here's a good reference:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html